# How to show relevant div when option selection using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html-select

I have multiple options in a select. If the select option is selected, a specific `<div>` will show.

Here's my html.

```js
$(function() {
  $("#reports").change(function() {
    if ($("#subjects").is(":selected")) {
      $("#subjects_form").show();
      $("#classes_form").hide();
      /* ... */
    }
    if ($("#classes").is(":selected")) {
      $("#classes_form").show();
      $("#subjects_form").hide();
      /* ... */
    }
    if (...) {
      ...
    } else {
      $("#subjects_form").hide();
      $("#classes_form").hide();
      ...
    }
  }).trigger('change');
});
```

```css
.form { display: none }
```

```html
<select class="form-control" id="reports">
  <option selected="selected" disabled="disabled" value="">Select Report to print</option>
  <option value="subjects" id="subjects">Subjects</option>
  <option value="classes" id="classes">Classes</option>
  <option value="teachers" id="teachers">Teachers</option>
  <option value="students" id="students">Students</option>
  <option value="departments" id="departments">Departments</option>
</select>

<div class="form" id="subjects_form">Subjects</div>
<div class="form" id="classes_form">Classes</div>
<div class="form" id="teachers_form">Teachers</div>
<div class="form" id="students_form">Students</div>
```

However the code above only works with the last option.

Comment: `Id` isn't valid attribute for `option` tag. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/option

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Id` isn't valid attribute for [`<option>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/option) tag. Use value attribute instead of id and select relevant div by it.

```js
$("#reports").change(function() {
    $(".form").hide();
    $("#" + this.value + "_form").show(); 
}).trigger('change');
```

```css
.form { display: none }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="form-control" id="reports">
  <option selected disabled value="">Select Report to print</option>
  <option value="subjects">Subjects</option>
  <option value="classes">Classes</option>
  <option value="teachers">Teachers</option>
  <option value="students">Students</option>
  <option value="departments">Departments</option>
</select>

<div class="form" id="subjects_form">Subjects</div>
<div class="form" id="classes_form">Classes</div>
<div class="form" id="teachers_form">Teachers</div>
<div class="form" id="students_form">Students</div>
<div class="form" id="departments_form">Departments</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `else if` statement to nest your conditions otherwise will you always run the last else condition along the firsts `if`'s.

```
$(function() {
      $("#reports").change(function() {
        if ($("#subjects").is(":selected")) {
          $("#subjects_form").show();
          $("#classes_form").hide();
          ...
        }
        else if ($("#classes").is(":selected")) {
          $("#classes_form").show();
          $("#subjects_form").hide();
          ...
        }
        else if (...) {
          ...
        } 
        else {
          $("#subjects_form").hide();
          $("#classes_form").hide();
          ...
        }
      }).trigger('change');
    });
```